Interpreting Positional Tolerance and its relation with rule 1 in GD&T
In GD&T, particularly in the ASME standards, it is widely understood that when positional tolerance applies to a shaft, it does not control the shaft's form.
So if positional tolerance does not control the form of a shaft, the shaft can bend within its allowable size limits if the shaft is specified with only a positional tolerance and no other geometric tolerances. For example, consider a shaft with a diameter of 40 mm, which has a size tolerance of ±1 mm and a positional tolerance of 1 mm regardless of feature size (RFS). When the shaft is manufactured at its least material condition (LMC), the shaft will have a size tolerance of 2 mm. This means it can bend up to 2 mm without exceeding the maximum allowable size of 40.1 mm, in accordance with Rule 1.
In this example, when we apply positional tolerance to the shaft at RFS, if the shaft's axis is intended to fit within the positional tolerance cylinder that has a diameter of 1 mm, it cannot fully utilize its size tolerance of 2 mm for bending or deviations in form for example like a 'C' shape when produced at LMC, as dictated by Rule 1 (if the entire axis of the shaft wants to remain within the 1mm positional tolerance cylinder, it will have less space for bending because the 1mm position does not allow for it). This indicates that positional tolerance does impact the shape of the shaft and we can not use rule 1 here. Conversely, if the shaft produced at LMC fully utilizes its 2 mm size tolerance and bends like a 'C' shape as much as permitted, the entire axis of the shaft will also bend, which could result in some sections of the axis falling outside the positional tolerance cylinder.
Based on these explanations, is there a contradiction in this situation? should we disregard Rule 1 in this case? or given that applying positional tolerance to a shaft requires the entire axis of the shaft to remain within a defined cylindrical space with a specified diameter(known as positional tolerance), can this guideline be overlooked in certain circumstances, permitting the axis of the shaft to extend beyond this established boundary? If not, how should we define the positional tolerance zone for a 'C'-shaped shaft, and what interpretation should we apply?

Can you please clarify what you mean by C-Shaped shaft? is the design intent of the shaft to be C shaped? Would a profile tolerance not be suitable in this instance?

In this example, we aimed to create a straight shaft, but it ended up curved like a 'C' or a banana. While the shaft meets size specifications, its curvature causes part of the axis to exceed the 1 mm positional tolerance zone (only the top and bottom are within it, while the middle is not). Is this acceptable since the entire axis should be within the 1mm positional tolerance zone? If not, does this imply that positional tolerance influences the shaft's form, even though it typically doesn't? Should we disregard Rule 1 in this case? What’s the correct interpretation, or is it a contradiction?

I think you have confused the use of positional tolerance in GD&T, positional tolerance is usually used to identify the location of a hole in a plate or a pin on a plate, so not a shaft on its own. Have you considered runout or total runout when discussing shafts?

Yes, here I mean applying positional tolerance to a pin on a plate. but for the hole also, there is no difference, it can also be in the shape of the letter C for holes too.

Should we disregard Rule 1 in this case?
I dont think you can disregard rule 1 in this case as there is no constraint on the form of the shaft. My understanding here is the the position tolerance is a refinement of rule#1
given that applying positional tolerance to a shaft requires the entire axis of the shaft to remain within a defined cylindrical space with a specified diameter(known as positional tolerance), can this guideline be overlooked in certain circumstances, permitting the axis of the shaft to extend beyond this established boundary?
You are correct the entire axis needs to be contained within the cylindrical tolerance. I cant think of a certain circumstance where the boundary can be allowed to be exceeded as you say. I think you are correct in your implementation of a pin on a plate. Source: https://www.gdandtbasics.com/true-position/
If not, how should we define the positional tolerance zone for a 'C'-shaped shaft, and what interpretation should we apply?
I dont see anything wrong with your definition of a tolerance zone, if the part is too much C shaped then it should fail inspection and not be used.
Source: I have recently completed a course on GD&T.

So you mean that when we apply positional tolerance to a shaft, the shaft can bend or deviate to some extent without having its axis go outside the position tolerance cylinder. This means it can use part of the size tolerance for bending rather than the entire size tolerance. If that's the case, then we can say that positional tolerance is controlling the form of the shaft, and the shaft cannot take on any form. Doesn't this contradict the statement that positional tolerance does not control form?

If you would like to control the form of a shaft you are better off using something like cylindricity or circularity. Position control is controlling I believe just the position of the axis relative to some datums whilst the form can take any shape it would like. i.e. the form is not constrained with position control. That is my understanding.
